# Conservation of classical linear momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Imagine a cat jumping off a roof onto a sledge on ice. Model this as simply as possible, e.g. no resistive forces, perfectly rigid cat, sledge and floor. Moreover, the cat and sledge move in a straight line.

The cat will have a vertical component to its momentum when it lands, but the sledge will - more or less - move off horizontally. What happens to the vertical component of momentum?

- Should we consider the Earth as a third body in the collision, and conclude that the Earth moves away with an immersurably small velocity?
- When performing calculations, can we simply ignore the vertical component post-landing?
- In reality, roughly what factor of the vertical motion's kinetic energy goes into heat, sound, vibrations, etc? (I don't mean list them one-by-one, just what is "non-Earth moving"?)

Comment: Indeed, the Earth absorbs the momentum, budging ever so slightly. And yes, you can assume the vertical component sort of 'dissapears': the normal force will cancel out the force the cat exerts on the sledge (unless the cat falls through the sledge!)

Comment: @Danu Thanks for the reply. Assuming the cat were to miss and bounce. In terms of calculations involving the coefficient of restitution, where there is both a horizontal and vertical component to *velocity*, would I apply the coefficient of restitution to the vertical component alone and then combine the post-collision, upward vertical component with the (unchanged) horizontal component to find the resultant post-collision *velocity*?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go back to before the cat jumps.

The earth-cat system has zero vertical momentum, and there are no ***external*** vertical forces on the system during the jump, flight and landing. So vertical system momentum remains zero.

Specifically, when the cat jumps, the earth rebounds.  As the cat moves vertically ***upward***, slowing as it goes, the earth continues to move away, more and more slowly.

When the cat reaches the peak of its movement, the earth stops its movement.

As the cat descends, the earth begins to move back towards the cat, faster and faster.

When the cat lands, its vertical (downward) momentum cancels out the vertical (upward) momentum of the earth.